# Creating a document with Pandoc

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I would like to create a **Haskell** program to automatically generate documents with **Pandoc**.

I created a small example document with the data types provided by [Pandoc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.16.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html#t:Pandoc) but when I launch my program, the ODT document is empty (But with the title `My own test file` in the properties) and the text file only contain the word `Template`.

This is the code snippet of my program :

```
import Text.Pandoc
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as Byt
import Data.Map (fromList)

main = do
  doc <- writeODT WriterOptions{ writerStandalone=True
                               , writerReferenceODT=Nothing
                               , writerUserDataDir=Nothing
                               , writerTemplate="Template"}  doctest
  let doc2 = writeMarkdown WriterOptions{ writerStandalone=True
                                        , writerTemplate="Template"}  doctest
  putStrLn $ show doctest
  Byt.writeFile "test.odt" doc
  writeFile "test.txt" doc2

doctest = Pandoc ( Meta {unMeta = fromList [("title", MetaInlines [Str "My own testfile"])
                                           ,("authors", MetaInlines [Str "My Name"])  ]} )
                          [Para  [Str "This",Space,Str "is",Space,Str "some",Space,Str "text"],HorizontalRule]
```

Both of the text file and the ODT docuement should contain the phrase `This is some text` and I don't understand why it doesn't appear.

**Do you know what I have made wrong ?**

**Do you have a working example on how to generate a Pandoc file with Haskell ?**

Comment: What happens when you try using `writeMarkdown` without specifying `writerTemplate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled the option `writerStandalone` which require a template to be defined to work properly. Personally, I don't use templates and I set the `writerStandalone` option to `False`

To make it work, use these `WriterOptions` for the plain text writer :

```
let textfile = writePlain WriterOptions{  writerStandalone=False
                                        , writerExtensions=plainExtensions
                                        , writerWrapText=True
                                        , writerColumns=80}  pandoc
```

for the docx writer :

```
docxfile <- writeDocx WriterOptions{ writerStandalone=False
                                   , writerReferenceDocx=Nothing
                                   , writerUserDataDir=Nothing
                                   , writerHighlight        = False
                                   }  pandoc
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting a correct `writerTemplate`.

You can tweak the template yourself, but should start from the default ones to understand their required structure. This is especially important for the ODT exporter, where the template needs to contain a quite verbose XML prelude.

I was able to get your code working by first loading the default templates, and then populating that with your document:

```
main = do
    Right odtTemplate <- getDefaultTemplate Nothing "odt"
    doc <- writeODT def{ writerStandalone = True
                       , writerTemplate = odtTemplate
                       }
                    doctest
    Byt.writeFile "test.odt" doc

    Right mdTemplate <- getDefaultTemplate Nothing "markdown"
    let doc2 = writeMarkdown def{ writerStandalone = True
                                , writerTemplate = mdTemplate 
                                } 
                             doctest
    writeFile "test.txt" doc2
```